# How create a link to open local file?

Tags: c#, html, .net, razor

I'm trying create a link to files located in local folder but it doesn't open the file. I'm using razor to create the links. My code is below:

```
<a href="@item.URL\@item.FileName" class="btn btn-info">@item.FileName </a>
```

and this what it outputs...

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="C:\Users\Dev\Documents\sp\Create.txt">Create.txt </a>
```

but it doesn't open the file for some reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file does not open because the web server (fortunately, for security reasons) does not have access to the Dev user's Documents folder.

Use a relative path under the web application's root directory.  App_Data is commonly used for that purpose, e.g.

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/App_Data/sp/Create.txt")">Create.txt</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
<a href="<%= Url.Content("~/sp/Create.txt") %>">Create.txt</a>
```

Comment: No, not if the file is actually located in `C:\Users\Dev\Documents\sp`

Comment: I guess, the question is about how to create a link ? it is another issue where the file is supposed to access.

Answer (score 0):

To call for a resource on your computer, you need to "tell" the browser it's a local path.

use:

```
<a href="file:///@item.URL\@item.FileName">
```

The `file:///` (notice the three slashes) will indicate the location of the target.